# How to make mixed statistical subplots using plotly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have some dataset in csv files(3 at total) and need to represent it in differents ways. They are necessarily line charts, box plots and histogram with kde(kernel density estimation).

I know how to plot them individually, but to make it more convenient I need to merge them into a single output. After consulting the reference I did write some code but it didn't run.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

y1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
y2 = np.random.randn(200)
y3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=2,
    column_widths=[0.6, 0.4],
    row_heights=[0.3, 0.6],
    specs=[[{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "box"}],
           [{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "dist", "rowspan": 2}]
           [{"type": "scatter"},            None           ]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y1,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                )
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y2,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(246, 52, 16)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                )
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y3,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(16, 154, 246)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                )
    row=3, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=y1)
    go.Box(x=y2)
    go.Box(x=y3)
    row=1, col=2
)

hist_data = [y1, y2, y3]

fig.add_trace(
    ff.create_distplot(hist_data,
                         bin_size=.02, show_rug=False)

    row=2, col=2
)

fig.show()
```

What is wrong with the code above, or how can I plot these charts with a unique output?

P.S. the line charts need to be separated for better visualization.

Comment: How did my edited suggestion work out for you?

Comment: You reach the point man! But the solution that I posted is less verbose.

Comment: You forgot the rug plot. I win =) Whatever, have an upvote!

Comment: Haha, for my purpose rug plot is useless because I work with many samples which cover the entire range (in this case the rug plot would be all covered) and my goal is to identify the locations of concentration. I have upvoted your answer too, and your topic about this same question :D

Comment: Appreciate it. SO needs more plotly action. Awesome answer by you and empet by the way. I picked up a few new things there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted this same [question](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-make-mixed-statistical-subplots/31203) on plotly forum, and the user [empet](https://community.plot.ly/u/empet), answered gracefully.

As I suspected, make_subplots() can`t handle a figure object, the way to go is "add figure data as a single trace at a time".

**Plot:**
[image: mixed-statistical-subplots]
**Code:**

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

y1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
y2 = np.random.randn(200)
y3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

colors = ['#3f3f3f', '#00bfff', '#ff7f00']

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=2,
    column_widths=[0.55, 0.45],
    row_heights=[1., 1., 1.],
    specs=[[{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "xy"}],
           [{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "xy", "rowspan": 2}],
           [{"type": "scatter"},            None           ]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y1,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='#3f3f3f',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y2,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='#00bfff',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y3,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='#ff7f00',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=3, col=1
)

boxfig= go.Figure(data=[go.Box(x=y1, showlegend=False, notched=True, marker_color="#3f3f3f", name='3'),
                        go.Box(x=y2, showlegend=False, notched=True, marker_color="#00bfff", name='2'),
                        go.Box(x=y3, showlegend=False, notched=True, marker_color="#ff7f00", name='1')])

for k in range(len(boxfig.data)):
     fig.add_trace(boxfig.data[k], row=1, col=2)

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
hist_data = [y1, y2, y3]

distplfig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, colors=colors,
                         bin_size=.2, show_rug=False)

for k in range(len(distplfig.data)):
    fig.add_trace(distplfig.data[k],
    row=2, col=2
)
fig.update_layout(barmode='overlay')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Second attempt after dialogue in the comments.

The following is the best I could do. It's an approach where I build an `ff.create_distplot` like in your sample code, and then "steal" the data and use it in a combination of `go.Histogram`, `go.Scatter` and `go.Box` objects to emulate the distribution and rug plots from the former.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# data
y1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
y2 = np.random.randn(200)
y3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

# subplot setupt
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=2
)

# Line [1,1]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, 
                        y = y1,
                        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                        mode='lines',
                        line=dict(color='rgb(0, 0, 0)',width=1),
                        showlegend=False,
                        name = 'series 1'
                        ),
             row=1, col=1
)

# Line [2,1]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y2,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(246, 52, 16)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=2, col=1
)

# Line [2,1]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y3,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(16, 154, 246)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=3, col=1
)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

# box plots [1,1]
fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y3, marker_color='rgb(16, 154, 246)'),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y2, marker_color='rgb(246, 52, 16)'),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y1, marker_color='rgb(0, 0, 0)'),
    row=1, col=2
)

# density plots [2,2]
hist_data = [y1, y2, y3]
group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']

# fig 2 is only there to produce the numbers to fill
# in later go.Histogram and go.Scatter
fig2 = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels)

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(fig2['data'][0],
                           marker_color='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                           showlegend=False
                          ), row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(fig2['data'][1],
                           marker_color='rgb(246, 52, 16)'
                          ), row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(fig2['data'][2],
                           marker_color='rgb(16, 154, 246)'
                          ), row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig2['data'][3],
                         line=dict(color='rgb(0, 0, 0)', width=0.5)
                        ), row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig2['data'][4],
                         line=dict(color='rgb(246, 52, 16)', width=0.5)
                        ), row=2, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(fig2['data'][5],
                         line=dict(color='rgb(16, 154, 246)', width=0.5)
                        ), row=2, col=2)

# sorry excuse for a rugplot [3,2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'y1':y1, 'y2':y2, 'y3':y3}, index = x)
df['rug1'] = 1.2
df['rug2'] = 1.1
df['rug3'] = 1
df.tail()
#f=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['y1'], y = df['rug1'],
                       mode = 'markers',
                       marker=dict(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', symbol='line-ns-open')
                        ), row=3, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['y2'], y = df['rug2'],
                       mode = 'markers',
                       marker=dict(color = 'rgb(246, 52, 16)', symbol='line-ns-open')
                        ), row=3, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['y3'], y = df['rug3'],
                       mode = 'markers',
                       marker=dict(color = 'rgb(16, 154, 246)', symbol='line-ns-open')
                        ), row=3, col=2)

# some manual adjustments on the rugplot
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0.9,1.3], tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)', size=14), row=3, col=2)
fig.update_layout(title ='Mixed statistical subplots', showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

---

#### EDIT - First attempt:

We'll start with this:

> What is wrong with the code above [...]?

That depends on what you're aiming to do here. But first of all, you are missing a lot of commas in places like this:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y3,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(16, 154, 246)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ) # <==================== insert missing comma !!!
    row=3, col=1
)
```

The next snippet leaves me puzzled:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(x=y1)
    go.Box(x=y2)
    go.Box(x=y3)
    row=1, col=2
)
```

There's at least *one* comma missing here, but It's still not very clear to me what you're trying to do. It seems to me that you'd like to put all boxes within the  same chart and plot it on top of the second column, but I don't think it would make much sense with the rest of the setup. And there are more worries ahead, because [it does not seem that you'll be able to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803324/plotly-how-to-combine-make-subplots-and-ff-create-distplot) your `ff.create_distplot()` in your setup at all.

The best I can do for you at the time being is to set up a plots for each series with a `go.Scatter()` in the first column and corresponding `go.Box()` in the right column like this:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

This is perhaps not 100% what you're looking for, but at least I think it makes sense to look at your data this way.

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

# data
y1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
y2 = np.random.randn(200)
y3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

# subplot setupt
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=3, cols=2
)

# raw data with go.Scatter
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, 
                        y = y1,
                        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                        mode='lines',
                        line=dict(color='rgb(0, 0, 0)',width=1),
                        showlegend=False,
                        ),
             row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y2,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(246, 52, 16)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x, 
                y = y3,
                hoverinfo = 'x+y',
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(color='rgb(16, 154, 246)',
                width=1),
                showlegend=False,
                ),
    row=3, col=1
)

# box plots
fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y1),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y1),
    row=2, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=y1),
    row=3, col=2
)

fig.show()
```

And then you can show the distribution of all the series together like this:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
hist_data = [y1, y2, y3]
group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
fig2 = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels)
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the commas correction, sorry if I didn't make myself understood, what I want is plot the line charts on the first column, put the 3 boxplots as one subplot on top of second column(since they are tiny) and use the rest of space to plot the histogram with kde. After more tryes, I guess that the problem is that create_distplot isn't a object of graph_objects() but a figure that's a collection of charts(in this case histograms, scatter plots and rug plots) and make_subplots() can't hold a figure as subplot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use matplotlib to merge all graphs in the same output you can use subplots, I don't know if it is what you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
y2 = np.random.randn(200)
y3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

def scatter_plot(ax,x,y):
    ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label')
    ax.set_title('Title')

def box_plot(ax,y):
    ax.boxplot(y)
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label')
    ax.set_title('Title')

def hist_plot(ax,y):
    ax.hist(y)
    ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label')
    ax.set_title('Title')

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5,ax6)) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
scatter_plot(ax1,x,y1)
scatter_plot(ax2,x,y2)
scatter_plot(ax3,x,y3)
hist_plot(ax4,y1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]